# jQuery to populate array-named form fields based on first entered value where number of fields is unknown

Tags: jquery, forms, field, populate

Greetings,

I have a form with a variable number of inputs, a simplified version of which looks like this:

```
<form>
<label for="same">all the same as first?</label>
<input id="same" name="same" type="checkbox" />
<input type="text" id="foo[1]" name="foo[1]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[2]" name="foo[2]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[3]" name="foo[3]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[4]" name="foo[4]" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[5]" name="foo[5]" value="" />
</form>
```

The idea is to tick the #same checkbox and have jQuery copy the value from #foo[1] into #foo[2], #foo[3], etc. They also need to clear if #same is unchecked.

There can be any number of #foo inputs, based upon input from a previous stage of the form, and this bit is giving me trouble. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't get any variation on `$('#dest').val($('#source').val());` to work.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery will fail to select by id `$('#foo[1]')` since it includes `[` and `]`, so I'm selecting the first element as `$('[id=foo[1]]')`. Then getting all next text boxes, then filtering them out if their id attribute does not match `foo[<digits>]`, and then either applying the same value as the first one, or clearing them depending on the checkbox state.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/mqXRg/)

```
$("#same").click(function() {
    var first = $('[id=foo[1]]');
    var next = first.nextAll(':text').filter(function() {
        return /foo\[\d+\]/.test(this.id);
    });
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        next.val(first.val());
    }
    else {
        next.val('');
    }   
});​
```

Although this works, it might just be easier to add classes such as `first` and `rest` to the HTML which would make things a lot easier.

```
<input id="same" name="same" type="checkbox" />
<input type="text" id="foo[1]" name="foo[1]" class="first" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[2]" name="foo[2]" class="rest" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[3]" name="foo[3]" class="rest" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[4]" name="foo[4]" class="rest" value="" />
<input type="text" id="foo[5]" name="foo[5]" class="rest" value="" />
```

The jQuery code then simplifies to:

```
$("#same").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.rest').val($('.first').val());
    }
    else {
        $('.rest').val('');
    }   
});​
```

Comment: Excellent answers, thanks so much :) I'm using the second method as it's exactly the kind of lateral solution that I knew was there but couldn't think of. Cheers!

Comment: Dang, Anurag, I want to be you!  Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $("input#same").click(function(){
      var checkBox = $(this);
       if (checkBox.attr("checked")){
         $("form input[name^=foo]").val($("input[name^=foo]:first").val());
        }else{
          $("form input[name^=foo]:not(:first)").val("");
        }
    });
```

EDIT: This code will only apply to input elements whose name starts with the string foo
[Example](http://jsbin.com/azida/3/edit)

Comment: Cheers, but I have other inputs of type text on the same page which I don't want auto-filled.

Comment: Ok, 1 second, I'll adjust my answer

Comment: Thanks mate, I accepted Anurags solution, but +1 for hanging in there :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution!  That's what we're all here for.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

http://jsbin.com/anone3/2/edit

Comment: Nice! Giving you +1 even though I've already accepted an answer :)