# jQuery – populating forms – classes dynamically named by php

Tags: jquery, class, forms

I’m new to jQuery and have the following problem: I’ve a couple of php generated forms. Each form has a checkbox and 5 input fields. Each input field has a class name generated with php: the first part of the name is always the same, but the end varies, in order to distinguish the classes (the id’s numbers are discontinued, for instance 1, 2, 5 etc).

The html ouput (no problem here, I guess):

```
<input class="same--1" name="same" type="checkbox" />
<div id="1"><input type="text" name="foo[]" class="first--1" value="" /></div>
<div id="2"><input type="text" name="foo[]" class="rest--1" value="" /></div>
<div id="3"><input type="text" name="foo[]" class="rest--1" value="" /></div>
<div id="4"><input type="text" name="foo[]" class="rest--1" value="" /></div>
<div id="5"><input type="text" name="foo[]" class="rest--1" value="" /></div>
<br></br>
<input class="same--2" name="same2" type="checkbox" />
<input type="text" name="foo[1]" class="first--2" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[2]" class="rest--2" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[3]" class="rest--2" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[4]" class="rest--2" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[5]" class="rest--2" value="" />
<br></br>
<input class="same--8" name="same8" type="checkbox" />
<input type="text" name="foo[1]" class="first--8" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[2]" class="rest--8" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[3]" class="rest--8" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[4]" class="rest--8" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[5]" class="rest--8" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript" >
```

I try to write the following jQuery function : when the first field is filled, the user selects the checkbox and the value is copied in the other field (as shown here [jQuery to populate array-named form fields based on first entered value where number of fields is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626318/jquery-to-populate-array-named-form-fields-based-on-first-entered-value-where-num) , but for multiple forms). The following code always returns an undefined value. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
$(function(){
    $.each('input[class^= "same--"]').click(function(){

        var id = $(this).attr('same').split('--')[1];

            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                $('.rest' + id).val($('.first' + id).val());
            }
            else
            {
                $('.rest' + id).val('');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: off-topic, but since I'm writing anyway, I should mention that your HTML code `<br></br>` is invalid: the `<br>` tag should not be closed like this, even in xHTML. Some browsers will interpret this as being two line breaks, which is probably not what you intended. You should close it as a stand-alone tag like this: `<br />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the class attribute.

I think you should actually do it like this:

```
var id = $(this).attr('class').substring(4);
```

You also don't need the $.each. This will work fine:

```
$('input[class^= "same--"]').click(function(){
```

Although I'm sure there is a better way of doing this using other jQuery selectors if you can change your html a bit to surround each group of inputs in a div.

Comment: Thank you very much InfernalBadger, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = $(this).attr('same').split('--')[1];
```

I think you meant

```
var id = $(this).attr('class').split('--')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery does allow selectors which specify substrings. You can do things like this:

```
$('[class^="same"]')
```

...which will search for elements with a class that begins with the word 'same'.

However, this would be easier (and less taxing on the browser) if you could simply reference a fixed class name. Since your code is generated by PHP, would you be able to modify it? HTML allows multiple classes to be specified for a single element, so you could continue to have the existing class and also have a more generic one. Something like this:

```
<input class="same--2 same" name="same2" type="checkbox" />
```

...then you can still use `same--2` where you're using it already, but you can use `same` where you want to apply something for all the linked elements, using a simple selector like this:

```
$('.same')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Spudley! It will help for sure, I didn't know that JQuery allows selectors which specify substrings. In this specific example, I will need the --x because I'm querying the database and get a lot of rows, and each one must be indentificated. Bye

Comment: @Raphael: glad it was useful. Re the class name needing --x - you can have it *both* ways, because you are allowed to specify multiple classes in an element. You can have `same--x` **and** `same` together at the same time.